# Musixtex: Guitar tab bending notation error, slur not visible

Tags: errors, bugs, musixtex

I'm trying to add a bending slur to a musixtex tablature.
The end result should look something like this (the upwards one would be enough, though):

[image]

I tried a promising script I found on [github (musixtab)](https://github.com/huljar/musixtab), but it only renders the 1/2 or full part of the bend, not the slur itself.

Any idea how to either fix the script (if it is not my fault of using it the wrong way ) or another way to get the desired result?

Here is my first try with the linked file. The hammer on / pull off also needed a manual slur to work, but those slurs are only visible when removing the:

```
\input{musixps}
```

which results in an error for the "\bendfull"

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input{musixps}
\input{musixtab}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}
    \setlines16
    \musicparskip
    \largemusicsize
    \setstaffs1{1}
    \setclefsymbol1{\tabclef}
    \nobarnumbers
    \let\extractline\leftline
\startextract
\Notes \irsluru03 \ltab2{15} \bendhalf{10}{10}{2}\en % <-- This \bendfull does not work. An error occurs without the input in line 3.

\Notes \tslur0d \ltab2{12}\en
\Notes\ltab3{14}\en
\Notes\ltab3{12}\en
\bar
\Notes\isluru0d\pulloff{2}{2}\ltab63\en % <-- This slur is only visible without the input in line 3.
\Notes\tslur0d\ltab60\en


\endextract
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One thing I found out is that in tablature writing there is no slur needed for the pullout. It would be written 3P0. So it is understandable the the slur is not produced automatically. With the rest of your problem I am stil struggling, too.

Comment: A second point which I just found, is that the "way back" is called "release", which is not provided for in the musixtab package. I think there will be need an entire new package which provides more guitar playing symbols.